# How many watchers we can have at max in a single page in an angular applicaiton without affecting the performance?

Tags: angularjs

How many watchers or scope variable can be kept in a page without affecting its performance of the page loading. Whether there is any limit for the scopes which used in terms of number or memory size?

Comment: whether 3rd argument of $scope.$watch is given takes significant effect for performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's more about ***what you watch*** and not how many watchers. I mean, an extremely heavy object / Array of objects watcher could affect performance while ten string watchers wouldn't.

I had a huge `formController` object in `$scope.form` being watched in my application which would change as we move through tabs (all tabs containing such forms). That watcher was consuming **7.x%** of total computing when measured in chrome devtools with timeline.

So, coming back to your question,  I don't think there can be a precise answer to that. Maybe your interviewer intended to see whether you know that there isn't a specific limit that only x number of watchers are allowed and it's more about what you are watching.

Comment: how many String watchers we can have in a Single page?

Comment: @tanmay `So, coming back to your question, I don't think anyone would have answer to that` -- why would you post an answer to a question no one can answer :P

Comment: @NaeemShaikh to let OP know, that sometimes, *there is no answer* is the answer :D

Comment: it should be comment instead of an answer right?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh look at the size of my answer. I would disagree that it should be a comment. I might be wrong but I am sticking to my opinion :)

Comment: ok just corrected the wording in your answer +1

Comment: @NaeemShaikh thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many watchers as you want.

There is no finite numbers of watchers, if you register 1000 watchers those will all work, if you register 10000 watchers, they will still all work.

I know some blogs mention 2500 watchers being the number after which performance will start degrading. I have never tested this, but I try to keep my watcher count as low as possible anyways.

In my current project which I joined half way through certain pages have around 3.5k watchers and the page works just fine.

All that being said, having too many watchers WILL affect performance.

Comment: Thanks @Giovanivercauteren for your answer. It really useful and I voted it up as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There is realy not an answer to this question. The biggest part that affects performance is **what you do** when the watchers are triggered. If you have logic calculations which loops through large arrays etc then a single watch may demand more then 1000+ simple watchers all together.